# How to extract w substring from a string in python when using a while loop

Tags: python

I have to write some lines of code that convert an hexadecimal value: eg "0x11cb"into a string having this form "\x11\xcb"

```
str=hex(4555) 
i=2
s=""
while i<len(str):
    s="\\x"+str[i,i+2,1]
    i=i+2
```

when I try to run this code, it returns an error message :

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `str`, as it will override standard `str` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it with `:` not `,`, as follows:

```
my_str=hex(4555) 
i=2
s=""
while i<len(my_str):
    s="\\x"+my_str[i:i+2:1]
    i=i+2
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that !! Thank you very much

Comment: @farfalla, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.